# how to use cssselector to convert css to xpath

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I would like to use some library to convert css selector to xpath. can anyone explain to me what is the meaning of return value and how I can cover to xpath like `//div//*[class@""]`

```
from cssselect import GenericTranslator

try
    sel = CSSSelector('div.w3-container.top')
except SelectorError:
    print('Invalid selector.')
print(sel)

sel:
'descendant-or-self::div[@class and contains(concat(\\' \\', normalize-space(@class), \\' \\'), \\' w3-container \\') and (@class and contains(concat(\\' \\', normalize-space(@class), \\' \\'), \\' top \\'))]'
```

Comment: It is the xapth, no conversion necessary. Since it starts with `descendant-or-self` its expecting that you start the query on the node you want to be root for your search. You could prepend `//` to get root.

Comment: The posted code doesn't work (CSSSelector not defined). Can you update with something that does work for others that view this later?

Answer (score 1):

`XPath(GenericTranslator().css_to_xpath('div.w3-container.top'))`

This will return the XPath of the given css class

Visit this [link](http://lxml.de/cssselect.html) for more details

Comment: Its already xpath... this creates an `lxml` XPath object where the xpath is pre-parsed and potentially faster if used multiple times. But not necessary.